# How to use the deja-backup

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, backup

I had asked the question 2 days before that I was able to connect to wifi but internet was not being accessed.

I think I have messed up with some conf files because I tried too many solution. So I came up to the point to re install ubuntu 14.04 again.

So my question was I have backup but how would I use that backup after re installing os again. Or what I thought is copy the backup folder with hard drive and then again use it after I re install..

This is what I have in my mind...if any one has good solution it would be warmly welcomed. I do not want to loose the data any way

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have your backup folder copied to an external location, because you need the backup files to restore your data. So do that first. I recommend Dropbox or an external hard drive. Also, you can use the program `Aptik` (not installed by default) to backup your installed packages list and PPAs.

Once you have backed up your backup data to a safe location, you can reinstall Ubuntu. Transfer your backup files onto the new system. Then open Backups and select Restore, and follow the instructions to restore your data. Do the same for Aptik to restore your installed programs and PPAs.